# jquery ajax data option needs two different selectors?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using jquery ajax option data like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/shop_pos/index.php?route=module/cart/callback',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: $('#product :input').not(".card_checkboxes"),
```

but what i really need is two different options like this

```
    data: $('#product :input').not(".card_checkboxes"), $("input[type=\'radio\']:checked"),
```

but not sure how to have two selectors like this...i know i can do this

```
   $('#product :input, input[type=\'radio\']:checked')
```

but i need the not condition only on the `$('#product :input')` portion....any ideas

Comment: The radio buttons are not inside the `#product` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
$( ':input:not(.card_checkboxes)', '#product' ).add( 'input:radio:checked' )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#product :input:not(.card_checkboxes), input[type="radio"]:checked')
```

- http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Answer (score 1):

Data either needs to be a query string or an object with a key value pair. I doubt you can pass in selectors like that as this will be a jQuery object you are passing in.

Comment: Invoking `serialize()` on that jQuery object will fix the issue (although it could be that jQuery does that by default).

Comment: Yes, he would have to explicitly call serialize on it, jQuery doesn't do this by default.